# Clutch Pedal will not depress

Tags: clutch, jaguar

On my 2000 Jaguar V6 3Lt I replaced the clutch friction plate and slave cylinder/thrust bearing. After bleeding the clutch, the pedal is hard frozen and will not depress. I flipped the clutch wrong way but still nothing doing. I put back the clutch. Bled again no joy. Car has 2000,000km

Comment: That's a lot of zeroes.

Comment: Yea, please check the km.  Depending on your convention for decimal points it looks like either two thousand kilometers or two million, both of which seem unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Have you put a brake hose clamp on the flexible hose of the clutch slave pipe and forgotten to remove it? Try disconnecting the pipe going into the slave cylinder and place a finger lightly over the end of it. Now have an assistant pump the clutch pedal, making sure the system is topped up with fluid. If the pipe pumps out fluid whilst disconnected then you can OK the master cylinder. Check that the small round seal is on the end of the pipe correctly and not adrift and blocking the fluid entry into the slave/concentric cylinder, they can come adrift. If OK, re-connect the pipe and try bleeding the clutch by closing the bleed nipple and pumping up system pressure, hold the pedal down and then open the bleed nipple, close the bleed nipple. Do this two or three times, or until the air in the system is bled. If the clutch does not now work correctly then you have re-assembled the clutch assembly incorrectly, which means the gearbox out again to rectify the fault.

Comment: That can be greatly simplified just by opening the bleeder while someone applies pressure to the pedal - if the pedal can be depressed while the bleeder is open (releasing fluid pressure), then the master cylinder is OK. Pinched line? Slave cylinder? Thowout bearing? Clutch pressure plate?

Comment: I follow your reasoning TD, but the V6 Jag is fitted with a concentric clutch slave cylinder. It may have a another name you know it by in the USA, but it has the slave cylinder, release mechanism and bearing all in one assembly.

Comment: OK - almost identical to the Jeep Cherokee (Chrysler years), then, except that the Cherokee's complete hydraulic clutch system (master cylinder, slave cylinder, piping, throwout, release) is only available as a complete sealed system - no individual parts can be replaced.